# i need something add a cumulative total column to my GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

when i try that code is give me a lot of errors i need something add a cumulative total column to my GridView that would show a cumulative total of one of the numeric columns in the row. like that [Running / Cumulative total in GridView column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342768/running-cumulative-total-in-gridview-column) i need exactly what solved here but code is not working

```
 debit  |credit |Total         
 2      | 0     | 2
 0      | 1     | 3
-0.5    | 0     | 2.5
 0      |1.5    |4
```

[image: the errors shown whem I tried to use the code in that question]

that my html

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="debit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="debit" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="d" ) ? Eval("stat_amount"): "0.00" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="credit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="credit" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="c" ) ? Eval("stat_amount"): "0.00" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

that my code with the error       [image]

Comment: if much better if you put your code inside at code tag ... .

Comment: Are you tested your code?, why use e.Row.DataItem("nPoints"), that its ok?

Comment: I added my code , html and the error

Comment: I hope my answer help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to find label with rowtype equal Footer (DataControlRowType.Footer), you need to use this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```